# Photo not loading in PhotoEditor View?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Photo not loading in PhotoEditor View?

```
2020-08-30 19:51:16.702 5017-29819/com.google.android.gms V/FA-SVC: Successful upload. Got network response. code, size: 204, 0
2020-08-30 19:51:16.707 4633-22280/com.google.android.gms E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting flex_time=9000 job_id=-1 period=20000 source=16 requires_charging=0 preferred_network_type=1 target_class=com.google.android.gms.measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService user_id=0 target_package=com.google.android.gms tag=Measurement.PackageMeasurementTaskService.UPLOAD_TASK_TAG task_type=0 required_idleness_state=0 service_kind=0 source_version=201214000 persistence_level=1 preferred_charging_state=1 required_network_type=0 runtime=1598797276704 retry_strategy={"maximum_backoff_seconds":{"3600":0},"initial_backoff_seconds":{"30":0},"retry_policy":{"0":0}} last_runtime=0
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:909)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:790)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:88)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1701)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1570)
        at aqcz.a(:com.google.android.gms@201214022@20.12.14 (040700-302211955):78)
        at aqco.a(:com.google.android.gms@201214022@20.12.14 (040700-302211955):167)
        at aqco.a(:com.google.android.gms@201214022@20.12.14 (040700-302211955):21)
        at aqco.a(:com.google.android.gms@201214022@20.12.14 (040700-302211955):161)
        at apyy.run(:com.google.android.gms@201214022@20.12.14 (040700-302211955):8)
        at tkq.b(:com.google.android.gms@201214022@20.12.14 (040700-302211955):12)
        at tkq.run(:com.google.android.gms@201214022@20.12.14 (040700-302211955):7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at tqq.run(:com.google.android.gms@201214022@20.12.14 (040700-302211955):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add your code in the question

Comment: There is no question.